# Identifying mystery electrical connector

Tags: connector

[image: mystery connector3]I've recently acquired a Japanese JRC NSC-16 Marine Reserve Transmitter at the rear of which is a connector that I'm not familiar with.  This connects the 24 volts supply to the unit, a number of pins being connected in parallel.  It will also carry the keying line.

I've tried to take pictures of the connector but they are pretty poor quality...

The connector has two rows of 6 pins, these are staggered between pin 2 and pin 3, and pin 8 and pin 9 so the mating plug can only be inserted one way.  There are two 'lugs' on the socket, presumably to secure the matching plug though these appear slightly bent...

I'd be grateful if anyone could identify this for me.

My apologies but being a newbie I can only post two images - and the ones I have posted are not very good...I'll see if I can post others later.

The connector carries the markings HRS followed by some other indistinguishable letters - they may be tot (in lower case) = HRStot?
The connector external measurements are ~390 x 140 mm

[[image: mystery connector1]]
[[image: mystery connector2]]

Comment: *"I've tried to take pictures of the connector but they are pretty poor quality"* So take better ones, duh!  There is no excuse.  Simple framing would be a good start.  Don't put the pertinent part in a small section of the top half of the picture, for example.

Comment: I was able to fix the include of the second image, it seems that you had a third image (but the link to that is missing).

Comment: The "HRS" means it's probably a Hirose part.

Comment: Olin - "So take better ones, duh! There is no excuse"  I am sorry, being partially sighted is merely something I have to live with.  However I promise I will try harder...

Comment: The "HRS" means it's probably a Hirose part.  Thanks brhans, that should get me started.

Comment: That thing is so old I would consider updating it an soldering new wires to the unit, put in a db9 or something like that

Comment: Claiming you're partially sighted doesn't change the fact that bad pictures don't convey the information we need to see.